# Matlab: how to pad ones to zero vector according to index vector?

Tags: matlab, math, vector

I am trying to find a more elegant way to pad ones to zero vector according to the index (1,3) of the four-length vector. How can you do it more elegantly/succintly?

**Input**

> (0,0,0,0) and (1,3)

**Intended output**

> (1,0,1,0)

**Trial**

```
>> B=[0,1,0,0;0,1,0,1;1,0,0,0;1,1,1,0];

>> find(B(1,:)==0 & B(4,:)==1)

ans =

     1     3

>> zeros(1,4)+[1,0,1,0]

ans =

     1     0     1     0
```

Basically `(1,3) --->  (1,0,1,0)`.

Comment: So (1,4) would become (1,0,0,1), etc? The one-based index of the tuples indicates where 1s appear, everything else is 0?

Comment: @Patashu yes (1,4) would be (1,0,0,1). Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is `I` such that `I=[0,0,0,0]` and the index pair is `ind=[1,3]`, then just

```
I(ind)=1;
```

This is a **very basic** matlab question, and I think just reading the [documentation about matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) should have sufficed.